# Use reference in Excel array literal

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is it possible to build an array literal element by element where each element is not a constant?

For example (using [this trick](https://exceljet.net/formula/return-array-with-index-function) to force `INDEX` to return an array):

```
=COUNTIF({[@ColumnB],[@ColumnD],[@ColumnF]}=INDEX([#Data],[@PrevRowLookup],N(IF(1,{[@ColumnB],[@ColumnD],[@ColumnF]}))),"=TRUE")
```

This will not enter, with the error being highlighted as `[@ColumnB]` with no further details given.

Comment: Does the  'index()` result have the same dimension as `{[@ColumnB],[@ColumnD],[@ColumnF]}=` ?

Comment: Yes, theoretically

Comment: Try separating the formula into 3 parts of `COUNTIF` .. make one for @ColumnB, one countif for @ColumnD, and one for @ColumnF.. principally.. if each parts works.. then your index() formula is not problematic || without a sample data/file, it was impossible for others to assist/try to replicate you error msg.

Comment: however, AFAIK, it'll be helpful you can share how you did the verification for the values in `INDEX([#Data],[@PrevRowLookup],N(IF(1,{[@ColumnB],[@ColumnD],[@ColumnF]})))` part of the formula. . || without a method to reproduce the error.. building the formula part-by-part is the only thing I can propose. (of course.. vba is always there at your disposal.. )

Comment: In the link you provided also proposed to [put braces around the 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47187863/can-excels-index-function-return-array/47189998#47189998) -> `N(if({1}`